# Django combine two querysets

Tags: python, django

My model:

```
 class Renewal(models.Model):
    policy_number = models.integerField()
    invitation_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Snapshot of my table is as follows

```
id  policy_number     invitation_date 
86  4353    2020-04-21 16:37:39.071941
87  4354    2020-04-21 16:38:16.082238
97  4355    2020-04-21 17:18:03.997882
99  4377    2020-04-21 17:26:58.414530
162 4218    2020-04-22 18:42:23.066879
167 4218    2020-04-22 18:29:10.571033
171 4218    2020-04-22 18:39:17.546550
175 4238    2020-04-23 17:35:54.444945
176 4238    2020-04-23 17:36:01.482819
177 4239    2020-04-23 17:42:15.056850
178 4238    2020-04-24 13:00:06.886101
179 4243    2020-04-24 13:00:32.098504
180 4241    2020-04-24 13:21:31.215547
181 4360    2020-04-29 13:48:18.765400
```

in my views, I'm trying to get policy_number in a given date range, as follows

```
def some_function(request):
    start_date = datetime.date.today()
    end_date = start_date - datetime.timedelta(days=5)

    renewals = Renewal.objects.filter(invitation_date__gt=end_date, invitation_date__lte=start_date)
    print(renewals)
```

what i'm getting : `[4238, 4243, 4241]`
expected answer : `[4238, 4243, 4241, 4360]`

this should ideally give me all renewal records created in last 5 days. However, if today is 2020-04-29, the last policy record should have been 4360, but my last policy record is 4241

Comment: Currently your filter checks if `invitation_date` is `>= today` and `< previous`, it should be `<= today` and `> previous`.

Comment: Your `4360` entry's date is not < today. Why would it be in the queryset?

Comment: I've also tried it this way, `renewals = Renewal.objects.filter(invitation_date__gt=end_date, invitation_date__lte=star_date)` yet i get the same result

Comment: I've updated the query in the main question, please review now

Comment: Can you try with filtering for the `date` only without time? e.g. `invitation_date__date__gt=end_date`

Comment: I got the solution to this, turns out, i should also pass time along with date. In this case, the start_date should have been `start_date=datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time.max)` and similarly for end date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Renewal with *policy_number* = 4360 has the *invitation_date* = 2020-04-29 **13:48:18.765400**, so if today is 2020-04-29, then your *start_date* will be 2020-04-29 00:00:00.0000, so if you want to take that renewal, you can do `start_date = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.time.max)` if you want to keep `invitation_date__lte=start_date`, if not, you may take the next day and do `invitation_date__lt=start_date`